# "Data variables must numeric or logical" while using grpstats in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, grouping

I have dataset with heterogeneous data. I want to count groups by some columns withou doing any additional operation like summing or averaging.

Nevertheless, [`grpstats`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/grpstats.html#inputarg_whichstats) function requires me numeric data fields:

```
>> grpstats(ds, {'Field1', 'Field2'}, {'numel'})
Error using dsgrpstats (line 256)
Data variables must numeric or logical.
Error in grpstats (line 135)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = dsgrpstats(x,group,whichstats,varargin{:});
```

How to overcome?

**UPDATE**

It is strange that I can't create SSCCE yet!

Small example works:

```
>> A={'Name', 'Gender'; 'Ann', 'female'; 'John', 'male'; 'Peter', 'male'}
B=cell2dataset(A,'ReadVarNames',true,'ReadObsNames',true)
grpstats(B,{'Gender'},{'numel'})
A = 
    'Name'     'Gender'
    'Ann'      'female'
    'John'     'male'  
    'Peter'    'male'  
B = 
             Gender      
    Ann      'female'    
    John     'male'      
    Peter    'male'      
ans = 
              Gender          GroupCount
    female    'female'        1         
    male      'male'          2
```

This is what I want. But in my example I get

```
Error using dsgrpstats (line 256)
Data variables must numeric or logical.
```

And should do the following trick

```
>> B.Dummy=ones(size(B,1),1)
B = 
             Gender          Dummy
    Ann      'female'        1    
    John     'male'          1    
    Peter    'male'          1    
>> grpstats(B,{'Gender'},{'numel'},'DataVars',{'Dummy'})
ans = 
              Gender          GroupCount    numel_Dummy
    female    'female'        1             1          
    male      'male'          2             2
```

**UPDATE 2 (CCSSE)**

I found it. Error occurs if dataset contains nested cell arrays:

```
A={'Name', 'Gender', 'Measurements'
    'Chanel Iman Robinson', 'female', {32, 23, 33}
    'Wilhelmina Cooper', 'female', {38, 24, 36}
    'Arnold Schwarzenegger', 'male', {57, 33, 29}};

B=cell2dataset(A,'ReadVarNames',true,'ReadObsNames',true)

grpstats(B, {'Gender'}, {'numel'})
```